# Card Authorization Failed DECLINED:1000410001:Invalid merchant: with mindbodyonline

Tags: php

I am trying to purchase a service by the CheckoutShoppingCart API with sendbox mindbodyonle. Then i am getting error

```
“Card Authorization Failed DECLINED:1000410001:Invalid merchant:"

Payment process is possible by the checkoutsoppingcart API with mindbodyonline sendbox for testing .
```

SAOP Request :

```
Array
(
[SourceCredentials] => Array
(
[SourceName] => ‘test’
[Password] =>………….
[SiteIDs] => Array
(
[0] => -99
)

)

[UserCredentials] => Array
(
[Username] => Siteowner
[Password] => apitest1234
[SiteIDs] => Array
(
[0] => -99
)

)

[ClientID] => 1234
[cartID] => 1
[InStore] => 1
[SendEmail] => 1
[CartItems] => Array
(
[CartItem] => Array
(
[Quantity] => 1
[Item] => SoapVar Object
(
[enc_type] => 300
[enc_value] => Array
(
[ID] => 1357
)

[enc_stype] => Service
[enc_ns] => http://clients.mindbodyonline.com/api/0_5
)

[DiscountAmount] => 0
)

)

[Payments] => Array
(
[PaymentInfo] => SoapVar Object
(
[enc_type] => 300
[enc_value] => Array
(
[CreditCardNumber] => 4111111111111111
[ExpYear] => 2016
[ExpMonth] => 06
[Amount] => 130

)

[enc_stype] => CreditCardInfo
[enc_ns] => http://clients.mindbodyonline.com/api/0_5
)    
)    
)
```

SAOP Response :

```
stdClass Object
(
[CheckoutShoppingCartResult] => stdClass Object
(
[Status] => InvalidParameters
[ErrorCode] => 9999
[Message] => Card Authorization Failed DECLINED:1000410001:Invalid merchant:

[XMLDetail] => Full
[ResultCount] => 0
[CurrentPageIndex] => 0
[TotalPageCount] => 0
)    
)
```